# Pine script alert

Tags: bots, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I'm building my startegy for my trading bot using pine script. Everything seems fine on the chart regarding the buy/sell signals. But my issues are on the alerts. Buy and sell alerts are triggered at the same time like the exact second. I failed on trade because of that.

Is there any way to remediate to that please ?

> ```
> strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long) 
> if  ta.crossover(close, sa) 
>     if(close > sma)
>         strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
>
> if  ta.crossunder(close,sa) 
>     strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
> ```

[Alert being triggered at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Snj.png)

[Setting alerts on TV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cYtq.png) 
I select my strategy here and then connect it to 3commas as explained by their docs

Comment: Please provide more info about issue. Code snippet, screenshot of your alerts window settings

Comment: Edited my post :)

Comment: I've also tried strategy.order instead of strategy.enter but nothing changes

Comment: Where is the code related to the alerts?

Comment: I use the alert functionality in the UI to set them added in the main post

Answer (score 0):

Okok I found a workarround, I needed to change the strategy into an indicator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).